# Is there any other way to use tail -f for grep -q && operation?

Tags: grep, pipe, tail

I found this solution: 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7178888/grep-q-not-exiting-with-tail-f

but is there any other possible?

UPD: I want to do `tail -f | grep -q something && echo 'found!'` but it doesn't work because tail -f prevents pipe from being closed, so `echo` command don't have a chance to be executed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try at your own risk:

```
tail -n 0 -f /tmp/bar | { grep -q -m1 zoo && echo found ; pkill -P $$ '^tail$' ; }
```

The `pkill` command is necesary if the match is in the last line. But may kill other `tail` process in background if any from the same parent.

Comment: Thanks a lot. An addition of curly braces and pkill part is a true awesomness.

Comment: Is it possible to make `pkill` to kill only that previous `tail` instead of all `tail` commands that run in current script?

Answer (score 1):

I believe you want to use `grep`'s `-q` or `-m` options. If you want to actually see the matching line, use `-m1`, which will print the line and exit (sending a `SIGPIPE` to `tail`, causing it to exit).  If you don't care to see the line, use `-q`, which will just exit when it finds the first occurrence.

Comment: " If you don't care to see the line, use -q, which will just exit when it finds the first occurrence." - that's the problem, `-q` doesn't exit, as you can see from my script sample.

Comment: Odd, it works for me. Regardless, the `-m` should work, just dump output to `/dev/null`